# How to send large string from JavaScript to Asp Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a PDF out of HTML code with `wkhtmltopdf`. In C# I am using `Process` to execute everything. I need to get from my HTML page certain `<div>` via JavaScript, and send all this content to my Asp. Currently trying to pass this string as argument into URL, but it is too long. Is there any other way to get big HTML string using JS, and send it to .NET Core, and make out of its content PDF?

```
function getDBData(src)
{
    let script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = backend + src;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function tableToPdf()
{
    // Add in htmlContent heade
    let htmlContent = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"table- 
                       style.css\" media=\"all\"/></head>";

     // Get all tables 
     let tables = document.querySelectorAll("#tableWrapper .col-lg-12");

     for(let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
     {
         // Get header of table
         let tableHeader = tables[i].querySelector(".tableHeader").outerHTML;

        // Get table content
        let tableContent = tables[i].querySelectorAll(".wrapper-table-section-library")[1].outerHTML;

        htmlContent += tableHeader 
        htmlContent += tableContent;
      }

    // Get width ant height of tableWrapper
    let height = document.querySelector("#tableWrapper").offsetHeight;
    let width = document.querySelector("#tableWrapper").offsetWidth;

    getDBData("getTablePdf?width=" + width + "&height=" + height +"&htmlContent=" + htmlContent + "&outputFileName=tables");        
}
```

Comment: Don't use query parameters to send large amounts of data, you are limited by the number of characters in a URL. Instead, `POST` the data in the message body.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: There is no link, that's just how things work.

Comment: Have you heard about [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore)? It is a wrapper over wkhtmltopdf and makes your task of creating the PDFs easy. Available as a nuget package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore)

Comment: Are you doing ajax request via `script` tag? Oh my

Comment: No, i have separate .js file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you already have a large string:

```
var largeString = '...';
```

One way to send this data from your script to your back-end, is to do an AJAX POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Sample/PrintDocument',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        dataToPrint: largeString
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(result) {
    // ... do something after the request was processed
});
```

Now, if you want to send this request whenever the user clicks on a "Print" button:

```
$('body').on('click', '#printButton', function (){
    // Do the POST request
    $.ajax({
        ...
});
```

Then in your controller you would have something like this:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> PrintDocument([FromBody] string dataToPrint)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your AJAX code written with JQuery? I am using pure JavaScript, is there version for pure JS version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blazor Server side, payload size of SignalR is litmited. Default size value is 32kb. You can change it but it is not good practice. Instance, you can split string to array substring or upload file.